# How to set a UICollectionViewCell as not selectable?

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

are there any ways to set a UICollectionViewCell as "not selectable" or is the only way to do this over the delegate Method `"didSelectItemAtIndexPath"` with querying for the right cell type?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just set the cells' 'setUserInteractionEnabled' property to 'No' in 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

UICollectionViewDelegate has a method for that: `shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath` ->  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDelegate/collectionView:shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:

Answer (score 3):

You can use delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

just return NO for index path of the cell you don't want to select.